# The sequence $a(n)=(2^n \bmod p)^{p-1} \bmod p^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences

Related to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390480/discrete-logarithm-and-the-sequence-an-gn-bmod-pp-1-bmod-p2).

Let $p$ be prime and $n$ positive integer.

Define $a(n)=(2^n \bmod p)^{p-1} \bmod p^2$

Let $D(n)$ be the base $2$ discrete logarithm of $a(n)$, i.e.
given $p,a(n)$ we have $2^{D(n)} \bmod p^2=a(n)$.
We can efficiently compute $D(n)=k(p-1)$ via p-adic logarithms
and code is given in the linked question.

Let $D(n)$ be computed via p-adic algorithms, probably differing
from the smallest logarithm by a small factor.

Strong numerical evidence suggests that three consecutive $D(i)$
satisfy:

$$ (D(n+2)-(D(n+3)+1)) (D(n+1)-(D(n+2)+1))(a_1 D(n+1) + a_2 D(n+2)+a_3 D(n+3)+a_4)\equiv 0 \pmod p \qquad (1)$$

for constants $a_i$.  The constants $a_i$ depend on $p$ only and
are determined by the first few values of $D(i)$ for which the other
factors don't vanish. We don't know closed form for $a_i$.

The numerical evidence is 50 primes greater than $10^6$
and $10^3$ triples per each prime. Also several primes greater
than $10^{50}$ were successfully tested.

> Q1 Is the above identity true?

Remarks:  Let $A=2^n \bmod p$. Then $a(n)=A^{p-1} \bmod p^2$
and $a(n+1)=(2A \bmod p)^{p-1} \bmod p^2$

Finding $n$ given $a(n)$ will break the discrete logarithm,
which would be major result.

Comment: What is your "strong numerical evidence"; Also, what are the values of $a_i$ predicted by these numerical experiments?

Comment: @MiloMoses I edited about the $a_i$.

Comment: @MiloMoses I edited with numerical evidence.

Answer (score 3):

Using the notation from [my answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/392313) to the previous question, we have
$$D(n+1)−(D(n+2)+1)\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$$
if and only if $g_0(n+2) = 2 g_0(n+1) - p$ and $g_1(n+2) \equiv 2 g_1(n+1) + 1\pmod{p}$, in which case
$$D(n+2) \equiv -(n+2 + \frac{2 g_1(n+1) + 1}{2 g_0(n+1)c})\equiv D(n+1) - 1 - \frac{1}{2 g_0(n+1)c} \pmod{p}.$$
Similarly, $$D(n+2)−(D(n+3)+1)\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$$ if and only if
$$D(n+3) \equiv D(n+2) - 1 - \frac{1}{2 g_0(n+2)c}\equiv D(n+2) - 1 - \frac{1}{4 g_0(n+1)c}\pmod{p}.$$
If both these incongruences hold, then
$$D(n+1) - 3D(n+2) + 2D(n+3) + 1 \equiv 0\pmod{p}$$
and so we can always take $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(1,-3,2,1)$.

Comment: Thanks. I think this deserves paper or a note. You didn't show infinitely many non-Wieferich primes in base 2, right?

Comment: Btw, this can be extended to $g>2$ -- we can construct a similar product of $2+(g-1)^2$ linear terms over $D(n),D(n+1),D(n+2)$ that is always $0$ modulo $p$.